# Why do some stocks have trading halts and what causes them?

Tags: stocks, trading

[image]

Even when trading hours were still on, one of the stocks I was watching has been put on halt. What does it mean? What are the reasons for a company's stocks to go on halt?

Answer (score 1):

The company may have put a trading halt due to many reasons, most of the time it is because the company is about to release some news to the market. To stop speculation driving the price up or down, it puts a halt on trading until it can get all the information together and release it to the market.

This could be news about an earnings update, a purchase of other businesses, a merger with another business, or a takeover bid, just to name a few.